# Fixing of a -Wconversion GCC warning for a loop variable

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, warnings, gcc-warning

I want to fix compiler warnings in existing code and came across the following free function:

```
std::uint16_t calculate_crc16(std::vector<unsigned char> const& kData) {
  std::int32_t result{0};

  // This nested loop iterates over each bit of the input data.
  for (unsigned char const& kByte : kData) {
    // TODO(wolters): Refactor to eliminate [-Wconversion] compiler warning.
    for (unsigned char j{1}; j; j <<= 1) {
      if (((result & 1) ? 1 : 0) ^ ((kByte & j) ? 1 : 0)) {
        result >>= 1;
        result ^= 0x9299;
      } else {
        result >>= 1;
      }
    }
  }

  return static_cast<std::uint16_t>(result);
}
```

The line below the `TODO` comment raises the following GCC v4.7.1 warning:

```
warning: conversion to 'unsigned char' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]
```

How can I refactor that code, to avoid the warning? I failed replacing `unsigned char` with `int` in the loop, since that changes the behavior.

Comment: considering all your integer literals are `int`s and they will promote all your `unsigned char` to `int`s, your use of `unsigned char` is simply non-sense.

Comment: OK, but then the inner loop won't work any longer since by doing that the size of the type has changed. `unsigned char` is used to represent raw bytes, btw. Maybe you could provide an example that improves the code?

Comment: just change `j` to `unsigned int`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might replace the `j <<= 1` with

```
 j = static_cast<unsigned char> (j << 1)
```

or perhaps even

```
 j = static_cast<unsigned char> ((j << 1)&UCHAR_MAX)
```

However, I find your code not very readable anyway.... Perhaps you might put some comment...

Comment: Since j is already an `unsigned char` you should be able to use `j = static_cast<unsigned char> (j << 1)` and avoid the c style cast